# Fusiontable Layer alternative for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code available for Google Maps which works with FusionTable Layer.

It changes based on the zoom level of the user.

The array `draw_str` and `draw_str_zoom` are dynamic and gets generated based on the API calls we make and the response we receive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 90%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      var layerState = [];
       var draw_str = '27089,27013,27053,27029,27035,27067,27081,27069,27155,27153,27131,27123,27109,27051,27043,27031,27027,27007,27005,27003,27001';
       var draw_str_zoom = '48131,48197,48459,48497,48163,48379,48403,48471,48499,48505,48067,48249,48289,48323,48351,48399,48467,48481,48485,48507,48031,48139,48187,48303,48315,48355,48409,48419,48429,48483,48489,48021,48027,48035,48053,48099,48143,48145,48157,48195,48225,48251,48271,48317,48319,48361,48427,48431,48463,48479,48043,48155,48215,48321,48343,48381,48425,48451,48469,48079,48135,48347,48363,48407,48477,48085,48201,48299,48325,48339,48413,48453,48503,48177,48291,48401,48423,48475,48089,48439,48095,48117,48253,48275,48329,48397,48441,48465,48259,48279,48335,48437,48487,48003,48045,48061,48121,48161,48209,48245,48281,48313,48375,48395,48445,48457,48473,48491,48501,48449,48435,48415,48405,48391,48387,48373,48371,48357,48349,48345,48337,48331,48309,48307,48293,48285,48277,48273,48265,48257,48255,48241,48231,48227,48223,48221,48219,48217,48213,48193,48189,48185,48183,48181,48175,48171,48167,48153,48151,48149,48147,48141,48133,48123,48119,48115,48113,48105,48097,48093,48091,48087,48077,48073,48071,48063,48059,48057,48055,48051,48049,48047,48041,48039,48037,48029,48025,48019,48015,48009,48005';


      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        layerState[0] = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                                        query: {
                                            select: '\'geometry\'',
                                            from: '1fio1qgy5HkinUDKqYvREIlSoBaHjl2RBe3DLJa38'
                                        },
                                        options: {suppressInfoWindows: true},
                                        styles: [{
                                                polygonOptions: {
                                                    fillColor: '#000000',
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.001
                                                }
                                            }, {
                                                where: "'GEO_ID2' IN (" + draw_str_zoom + ")",
                                                polygonOptions: {
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.3
                                                }
                                            }]
                                    });
                                    layerState[0].setMap(map);


       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        var zoom_level = map.getZoom();


        if (zoom_level >= 6 && zoom_level < 7) {

                clearRegion(zoom_level);

               layerState[0] = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                                        query: {
                                            select: '\'geometry\'',
                                            from: '1fio1qgy5HkinUDKqYvREIlSoBaHjl2RBe3DLJa38'
                                        },
                                        options: {suppressInfoWindows: true},
                                        styles: [{
                                                polygonOptions: {
                                                    fillColor: '#000000',
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.001
                                                }
                                            }, {
                                                where: "'GEO_ID2' IN (" + draw_str + ")",
                                                polygonOptions: {
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.3
                                                }
                                            }]
                                    });
                                    layerState[0].setMap(map);


        }

    });

       function clearRegion(level) {

      layerState.forEach(function(kml) {
            kml.setMap(null);
        });

    }


}                             

     // }
    </script>
    <script async defer 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMtoh9P3UkoxbXndKu_HOP7KsVwTRvxGU&callback=initMap">
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Google Fusion Table is going down - https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417

Is there a way I could create this similar map with all the functionality without using FusionTable layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Fusion Tables will not be available after Dec. 3, 2019, I suggest:

- Download your tables as KML files, 
  https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2548807?hl=en
- Host your KML files at a publicly accessible URL that does not require authentication to access. This is because Maps JavaScript API uses a Google hosted service to retrieve and parse KML files for rendering.
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer
- Finally, display the information of your KML files in a Google map and sidebar. 
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Alternatively, you can host your KML files in the same domain where your webpage is, but for that you'll need a library like GeoXML3:

- Examples: 
  http://www.dyasdesigns.com/geoxml/GeoXmlSamples.html
- Repository that I used, EDIT 1 below: 
  https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/tree/master/kmz

EDIT1: With GeoXML3, dynamically styling from `draw_str` would be:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="geoxml3.js"></script>
<script>

  var draw_str = [/* your array */];

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
    });

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map,zoom: false}); // zoom needs to be set to false to keep mapOptions intact.
    myParser.parse('Counties.kml'); // our Document (myParser.docs[0]) is the only parsed kml

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

        var polygonOptions =  {fillColor: "#000000" , fillOpacity: 0.001}; 
        var polygonOptionsID2 = {fillOpacity: 0.3}; 
        var zoom_level = map.getZoom();

        if (zoom_level >= 6 && zoom_level < 7) {

            for (var i = 0; i < draw_str.length; i++) {

                for (var j = 0; j < myParser.docs[0].placemarks.length; j++) {
                    if (draw_str[i] == myParser.docs[0].placemarks[j].vars.val.GEO_ID2) { // GEO_ID2 is stored as Extended Data for every placemark (myParser.docs[0].placemarks is an array with 3250 entries)
                        myParser.docs[0].gpolygons[j].setOptions(polygonOptionsID2); // myParser.docs[0].gpolygons is an array with 3250 polygons
                    } else {                            
                        myParser.docs[0].gpolygons[j].setOptions(polygonOptions);
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    });  
}                             

</script>
```

It will be a bit slow since the KML downloaded from Fusion Tables has more than `15 MB`

EDIT2: fully functional demo consuming both `draw_str` and `draw_str_zoom`, dependent on having both GeoXML3.js and the KML downloaded from the Fusion Table page, referenced in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
       }
     </style>
   </head>
  <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="static/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script>

   var draw_str = "27089,27013,27053,27029,27035,27067,27081,27069,27155,27153,27131,27123,27109,27051,27043,27031,27027,27007,27005,27003,27001";
   var draw_str_zoom = "48131,48197,48459,48497,48163,48379,48403,48471,48499,48505,48067,48249,48289,48323,48351,48399,48467,48481,48485,48507,48031,48139,48187,48303,48315,48355,48409,48419,48429,48483,48489,48021,48027,48035,48053,48099,48143,48145,48157,48195,48225,48251,48271,48317,48319,48361,48427,48431,48463,48479,48043,48155,48215,48321,48343,48381,48425,48451,48469,48079,48135,48347,48363,48407,48477,48085,48201,48299,48325,48339,48413,48453,48503,48177,48291,48401,48423,48475,48089,48439,48095,48117,48253,48275,48329,48397,48441,48465,48259,48279,48335,48437,48487,48003,48045,48061,48121,48161,48209,48245,48281,48313,48375,48395,48445,48457,48473,48491,48501,48449,48435,48415,48405,48391,48387,48373,48371,48357,48349,48345,48337,48331,48309,48307,48293,48285,48277,48273,48265,48257,48255,48241,48231,48227,48223,48221,48219,48217,48213,48193,48189,48185,48183,48181,48175,48171,48167,48153,48151,48149,48147,48141,48133,48123,48119,48115,48113,48105,48097,48093,48091,48087,48077,48073,48071,48063,48059,48057,48055,48051,48049,48047,48041,48039,48037,48029,48025,48019,48015,48009,48005";

   var draw_strArray = draw_str.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number); 
   var zoomArray = draw_str_zoom.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number); 

   var tempOptions = {fillColor: "#FFFF00", strokeColor: "#000000", fillOpacity: 0.9, strokeWidth: 10};

   var geoXmlDoc;

  function initMap() {
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
    });

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map,zoom: false, afterParse: useTheData });
    myParser.parse('static/Counties.kml');


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

        var zoom_level = map.getZoom();

        if (zoom_level >= 6 && zoom_level < 7) {

            for ( i = 0; i < draw_strArray.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; j++) {

                    if (draw_strArray[i] == geoXmlDoc.placemarks[j].vars.val.GEO_ID2) {
                        geoXmlDoc.gpolygons[j].setOptions(tempOptions);
                    }
                }
            }       
        } else {

            for ( i = 0; i < draw_strArray.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; j++) {

                    if (draw_strArray[i] == geoXmlDoc.placemarks[j].vars.val.GEO_ID2) {
                        geoXmlDoc.gpolygons[j].setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.0});                  
                    }

                }

            }



        }

    });     

 function useTheData(doc) {
         geoXmlDoc= doc[0];
            for ( i = 0; i < zoomArray.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; j++) {

                    if (zoomArray[i] == geoXmlDoc.placemarks[j].vars.val.GEO_ID2) {
                        geoXmlDoc.gpolygons[j].setOptions(tempOptions);
                    }
                }
            }           
  };

} 


</script>
<script async defer 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMtoh9P3UkoxbXndKu_HOP7KsVwTRvxGU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The question is how to dynamically query without fusion table? Even if I download the files as KML, how would the dynamic query work?

Comment: How to convert to GeoJSON? Can you create code to output what I require using GeoJSON?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand. My fusion table is publicly accessible - https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1fio1qgy5HkinUDKqYvREIlSoBaHjl2RBe3DLJa38#rows:id=3

Comment: How are you using - `draw_str`

Comment: Can you please make code a working example? So I can see it functional.

Comment: I meant - can you please add my exact counties in draw_str so we can see?

Comment: This is great. Just one question - is it possible to remove the geoxml layer if let's say a user zooms in to level 8?

Comment: `if (zoom_level ==8) {   
                for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.gpolygons.length; i++) {
                        geoXmlDoc.gpolygons[i].setOptions(transparentOptions);
                 }
    }` where in `transparentOptions` you set opacities to `0.0`

Comment: Or, more simpler  `geoXmDoc.hideDocument();`  and then `geoXmlDoc.showDocument();`

Comment: can you please share the demo link again? For some reason my code is not working :(